# How to test my code

Tags: python, function, class, testing, python-3.3

I'm having trouble getting the output I want for my code. I want to test a class and the functions defined in the class. This is my code:

```
class Book:
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, author, title, book_id):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.book_id = book_id      
    def __str__(self):
        s = "Books("+self.author+", "+self.title+", "+self.book_id+")"
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

What I did to try to attempt to test it is this:

```
 >>> author="Dr. Suess"
>>> title="The Cat in the Hat"
>>> book_id="12345"
>>> Book
<class '__main__.Book'>
>>>
```

the output I get is the last line. I'm probably doing it wrong but I don't know how to test it. If someone can show me that would be great!

Comment: What is the output you want?

Answer (score 2):

When you type `Book` into the interpreter, you're getting the *actual `Book` class' representation* as output. `__repr__` and `__str__` both refer to the *instance* of a `Book`, not to the class itself. So to test this, you have to instantiate a `Book`:

```
>>> b = Book("Dr. Suess", "The Cat in the Hat", "12345")
>>> b
"Books(Dr. Suess, The Cat in the Hat, 12345)"
```

Remember - a class is like a blueprint for an instance. In this case, `Book` defines what it means to be a `Book`, but it doesn't actually define an actual `Book` object - to do that, you need to make a `Book` instance using the code I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Book
<class '__main__.Book'>
```

When one does the above in the console, it does not call the `__repr__` method created on *instance*. Let me explain, `Book` is merely a class object, its not an instance, because you have not called any arguments to it, however, if you *do* call arguments, this is what you get:

```
>>> from Books import Book
>>> Book
<class Books.Book at 0x027B0AE8>
>>> Book("Hello", "World", '1234')
Books(Hello, World, 1234)
```

As you can see, *because* we created an instance of a method, we were able to get the `__repr__` to be called.